# One service or multiple services

Tags: android, android-service

I have an application which will have Sticky Service. This service does GPS location queries all the time. However, I want to have tasks done when I alarm is expired/Bluetooth is connected. These are short lived tasks and I wanted to have services for them . My question is:

Should I use one service for everything and based on the values I get in the OnStartCommand, I would do the required task.

Or should I create  separate service class for each one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate service for each unrelated task.  It will leave your code less confusing.

Comment: Would you give me the same advice for the following case scenario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77631794/switch-between-multiple-android-services-instead-of-one-single-service-which-on?