# Switch between multiple android services instead of one single service? Which one is more prone to memory leaks and more performant?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

I have currently 4 services, each performs a specific task in the background on the text received from the user.
Which service is going to be started is decided depending on the text format.
Let me give you two examples.

If I read text `December 9, 2023` I would start `DateType1Service`

If I read text `9/12/2023` I would start `DateType2Service`.

Since having both services could create conflict on the actions performed in the foreground, every time I need to check if other services are running, stop them and start the appropriate service. That's what I meant with "switch" in the title of my question.

Please note that this approach doesn't go necessarily against the rule of "long-running executable in the background" of a Service definition since if texts of the same type are detected then the service is never stopped, unless the system decide to kill it.

Now this architecture of having distinct services is of course great for code-readability but wouldn't be overall a better solution (performance is the main focus) to put everything inside one single service instead of having distinct services?